Generate a PCIe x2 upstream port out of two PCIe x1 ports
I'm wondering if it is possible to generate an PCIe x2 upstream port out of two PCIe x1 lanes as seen in the image below.

Let me explain: The SOC provides one PCIe lane to the first packet switch. This switch is configured with upstream port as PCIe x1 and 4 downstream ports with each PCIe x1. Imagine (for whatever reason) I have another packet switch with upstream port configured as PCIe x2 which provides another 4 downstream ports each PCIe x1. Is this even possible?
Is the packet switch able to combine two PCIe x1 into one PCIe x2 as upstream port? If yes, is the first packet switch involved in some way?
The packet switch may be the device PI7C9X2G606PR for example with mode 506 or 505.

Aggregation is not possible unless the upstream port supports combining two of its downstream ports into a single x2 link - which is not a PCIe feature, but entirely down to the designer of that IC. It appears that switch only supports X2 on the upstream port

Your question is a bit unclear to me. That particular device PI7C9X2G606PR can be configured to support either PCIe x2 or PCIe x1 upstream ports. But the question is, can 2 PCIe x1 downstream ports combined into one x2 link. What is the role of the SOC? Is he involved in some way?

@bkausbk and what Tom says "it depends on whether your first switch can do aggregation on the downstream ports. The second switch being able to do 2x on the upstream port is necessary, but not sufficient."

@bkausbk But: the setup you propose seems to make no sense to me – or are you expecting device-to-device transactions between the two devices attached (single laned) directly to the first switch with two or more devices attached (single laned) to the second switch, which in sum exceed the bandwidth of a single lane? Because that is the only possibility having an x2 link between the two switches gives you any benefit, according to your schematic.

@MarcusMüller The connection SOC to the first switch supposed to be a x2 or x4 upstream link. My idea is, if the second switch is attached by a x2 link, it would allow higher throughput for devices attached to the second switch.

but it's not a x2 or x4 upstream link in your description of the problem, very explicitly!

@MarcusMüller That's correct!

It is generally not possible to take multiple links from an upstream device (the first packet switch in your diagram) and connect them to a single downstream device. This would be called aggreation and is not a feature of PCIe.
The only way it would be possible is if the IC designer added a non-standard feature to allow it. In some switches, the downstream ports are actually full width (e.g. a x4 port), and can then be made smaller through bifurcation, allowing bifurcations such as [x1,x1,x2] . Some of the switches from Microsemi (now Microchip) support this.
The PI7C9X2G606PR does not have support for forming a single x2 downstream port from two of its x1 downstream ports. So what you want to build is not possible with this particular switch.
